# Как запретить вызов экземпляров страницы больше 1 раза?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

Я вызываю переход к другой странице методом `Frame.Navigate()`. И если несколько раз тапнуть на кнопку, то программа и откроет несколько экземпляров страницы. Я конечно могу поставить сразу `isEnabled = false` на кнопке, но это вариант не самый лучший, как я понимаю. Собственно сабж.

Comment: Сделайте открывемую страницу синглтоном. Создался один раз, остальные разы - используется существующий.

Comment: @Monk а не подскажите как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (frame.CurrentSourcePageType != typeof(LALA))
{
 frame.Navigate(typeof(LALA));
}
```

Ответ я получил вот [ТУТ](https://toster.ru/q/285258).

Comment: `typeof(LALA) != null` - в каком случае typeof может вернуть null?

Comment: @Qwertiy поправил, спасибо.